# Splitting specific column values into multiple columns

Tags: r

-Dataset

```
ID<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
method<-c("cheque","DD","DD","Cheque","NetBank","NetBank","Cash")
type<-c("Type1","Type1","Type2","Type2","Type3","Type3","Type4")    
aid<-c("A1","A1","A2","A2","A3","A3","A4")  
month<-c("JAN","JAN","FEB","FEB","MAR","MAR","APR")
year<-c(2016,2016,2015,2015,2017,2017,2018)
Outcome<-c("Positive","Positive","Negative","Negative","Medium","Medium","Neutral")
ser_no<-c("A00001","A00001","A00002","A00002","A00003","A00003","A00004")
Units<-c(100,200,300,400,500,600,700)
amt<-c(1000,1500,2000,3000,4000,2500,6000)
user_cnt<-c(20,20,15,15,32,32,44)

data<-data.frame(ID=ID,type=type,aid=aid,month=month,year=year,Outcome=Outcome,ser_no=ser_no,Units=Units,amt=amt,user_cnt=user_cnt,method=method)
```

R> data

```
  ID  type aid month year  Outcome ser_no Units  amt user_cnt  method
  1 Type1  A1   JAN 2016 Positive A00001   100 1000       20  cheque
  2 Type1  A1   JAN 2016 Positive A00001   200 1500       20      DD
  3 Type2  A2   FEB 2015 Negative A00002   300 2000       15      DD
  4 Type2  A2   FEB 2015 Negative A00002   400 3000       15  Cheque
  5 Type3  A3   MAR 2017   Medium A00003   500 4000       32 NetBank
  6 Type3  A3   MAR 2017   Medium A00003   600 2500       32 NetBank
  7 Type4  A4   APR 2018  Neutral A00004   700 6000       44     


Output<-sqldf("select type,aid,month,year,Outcome,ser_no,count(distinct ID) as members,count(type) as entries,sum(UNITS) as UNITS,sum(amt) as amt,
min(amt) as LowestAmt,max(amt) as HighestAmount,AVG(amt) as Mean,user_cnt,cast (count(distinct ID) as real)/user_cnt as Suggestion 
from data group by type,aid,month,year,Outcome,ser_no")
```

R>Output

```
 type aid month year  Outcome ser_no members entries UNITS  amt LowestAmt HighestAmount Mean user_cnt Suggestion  
 Type1  A1   JAN 2016 Positive A00001       2       2   300 2500      1000          1500 1250       20 0.10000000     
 Type2  A2   FEB 2015 Negative A00002       2       2   700 5000      2000          3000 2500       15 0.13333333 
 Type3  A3   MAR 2017   Medium A00003       2       2  1100 6500      2500          4000 3250       32 0.06250000 
 Type4  A4   APR 2018  Neutral A00004       1       1   700 6000      6000          6000 6000       44 0.02272727
```

- I want to **add method column** from `data` in my output.

  Method column can have only four value 1.Cheque 2.DD 3.NetBank
  4.Blank denotes cash

I want to add a method column values in output below(Check last four columns). Can it be done without `sqldf`. 
I am trying to find the occurence of method values in a group.

Example: As per GROUP BY clause the row one has `1 Cheque` and `1 DD` value thus there count is displayed as `1`.  `Netbank` and `Cash` values are not present thus there count is 0.
As per GROUP BY clause the row three has`2 Netbank` values  thus there count is displayed as `2` and as there are no `Netbank`,`Cash` and `Cheque` values thus there count is 0.

```
 type aid month year  Outcome ser_no members entries UNITS  amt LowestAmt HighestAmount Mean user_cnt Suggestion    Cheque      DD  Netbank     Cash
 Type1  A1   JAN 2016 Positive A00001       2       2   300 2500      1000          1500 1250       20 0.10000000      1         1      0         0
 Type2  A2   FEB 2015 Negative A00002       2       2   700 5000      2000          3000 2500       15 0.13333333      1         1      0         0
 Type3  A3   MAR 2017   Medium A00003       2       2  1100 6500      2500          4000 3250       32 0.06250000      0         0      2         0
 Type4  A4   APR 2018  Neutral A00004       1       1   700 6000      6000          6000 6000       44 0.02272727      0         0      0         1
```

Answer (score 2):

I could not solve the case issue on 'cheque' as tolower is not working under sqldf.So included both the options.

```
sqldf("select type
,aid
,month
,year
,Outcome
,ser_no
,count(distinct ID) as members
,count(type) as entries
,sum(UNITS) as UNITS
,sum(amt) as amt
,min(amt) as LowestAmt
,max(amt) as HighestAmount
,AVG(amt) as Mean
,user_cnt
,cast (count(distinct ID) as real)/user_cnt as Suggestion
,count(case when lower(method)='cheque' then method  end ) as cheque 
,count(case when method ='DD' then method  end ) as DD 
,count(case when method ='NetBank' then method  end ) as NetBank 
,count(case when method ='Cash' then method  end ) as Cash 
from data
group by type,aid,month,year,Outcome,ser_no")
```

Answer (score 1):

with data table :

```
library(data.table)
DT <- setDT(data)
DT[,method := tolower(method)] # to avoid different count with upper and lower case
plouf<-dcast(DT[,.N, by = .(type,method)],type~ method)
plouf[is.na(plouf)]<-0 

    type cash cheque dd netbank
1: Type1   0     1    1      0
2: Type2   0     1    1      0
3: Type3   0     0    0      2
4: Type4   1     0    0      0
```

Here `DT[,.N, by = .(type,method)]` counts the different methods, and dcasdt transform it into large format.
You can then merge with your output

```
Output <- setDT(Output)
Output[plouf, on = "type"]

    type aid month year  Outcome ser_no members entries UNITS  amt LowestAmt HighestAmount Mean user_cnt Suggestion cash
1: Type1  A1   JAN 2016 Positive A00001       2       2   300 2500      1000          1500 1250       20 0.10000000    0
2: Type2  A2   FEB 2015 Negative A00002       2       2   700 5000      2000          3000 2500       15 0.13333333    0
3: Type3  A3   MAR 2017   Medium A00003       2       2  1100 6500      2500          4000 3250       32 0.06250000    0
4: Type4  A4   APR 2018  Neutral A00004       1       1   700 6000      6000          6000 6000       44 0.02272727    1
   cheque dd netbank
1:      1  1      0
2:      1  1      0
3:      0  0      2
4:      0  0      0
```

Comment: Is there any way to get the expected output in one query itself rather than appending it? I am grouping on **Six Columns** `type,aid,month,year,Outcome,ser_no` and not just on `type`. `dcast(data, type + month + year + Outcome + aid + ser_no ~ method, fun.aggregate = length)`

Comment: you could use the same code here by creating a grouping variable :
`DT[,grp := paste(type,aid,month,year,Outcome,ser_no,sep = "_")]`
And then `dcast(DT[,.N, by = .(grp,method)],grp ~ method)`

Answer (score 1):

The whole aggregation can be done in one statement using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[
  , .(members = uniqueN(ID), entries = .N, UNITS = sum(Units), amt = sum(amt), 
      LowestAmt = min(amt), HighestAmount = max(amt), Mean = mean(amt), 
      user_cnt = first(user_cnt), Suggestion =  uniqueN(ID) / first(user_cnt),
      Cheque = sum(tolower(method) == "cheque"), DD = sum(tolower(method) == "dd"), 
      NetBank = sum(tolower(method) == "netbank"), 
      Cash = sum(tolower(method) %in% c("cash", ""))), 
  by = .(type, aid, month, year, Outcome, ser_no)]
```

> ```
>     type aid month year  Outcome ser_no members entries UNITS  amt LowestAmt HighestAmount Mean user_cnt Suggestion Cheque DD NetBank Cash
> 1: Type1  A1   JAN 2016 Positive A00001       2       2   300 2500      1000          1500 1250       20 0.10000000      1  1       0    0
> 2: Type2  A2   FEB 2015 Negative A00002       2       2   700 5000      2000          3000 2500       15 0.13333333      1  1       0    0
> 3: Type3  A3   MAR 2017   Medium A00003       2       2  1100 6500      2500          4000 3250       32 0.06250000      0  0       2    0
> 4: Type4  A4   APR 2018  Neutral A00004       1       1   700 6000      6000          6000 6000       44 0.02272727      0  0       0    1
> ```

In case there are more than just 4 different values in `method` I would suggest other approaches like `dcast()` and join.

Comment: It is much slower than PIG answer on dataset of 1.4 million rows. PIG answer takes 17 seconds where data.table takes 1 minute 14 seconds. @Uwe